# the value of a comparison expression in perl

Tags: perl

I'm rather confused about the value of a comparison expression in perl：

```
   print "why... ",1>2, "\n";
```

I get the following results：

```
   why...
```

So, why the result of "1>2" is empty ? The book tells me that "$a>$b" is 0 or 1 .

Comment: *The book tells me ...* - which book?

Comment: It's sort of true, but it's sort of not. 0 is false and 1 is true. But 2 is true as well.

Comment: It looks like your book is wrong. It would be useful to know which book you're reading so we can discourage people from reading it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, grab yourself a coffee, as it's time to go down the rabbit hole of perl and [dualvars.](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#dualvar)

The thing that's happening here is - perl does some magic with 'boolean' values results.

As you may know - in perl "false" is (pretty much) anything that evaluates to zero or an empty string.

So `0` is false, but so is `''` (and a bunch of other things).

Perl usually infers from context, and the magic 'just works'.

```
print "yes" if 1>2; #just works.
```

But... what about printing the result of your boolean? Well, as it turns out, because it could be *either* "empty string" or "0" perl creates a dualvar.

This is specifically a thing that has *both* values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw ( isdual dualvar );

my $result = 1>2;

if ( isdual ( $result ) ) { 
   print "\$result is a dualvar\n";
}

print "Number:", 0+$result,"\n";
print "String:",''.$result,"\n";
```

If you tried these operations on a *normal* value:

```
my $number = '';
print 0+$number;
```

You would get

```
Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+)
```

You can replicate this magic, using `dualvar`:

```
my $thing = dualvar ( 666, "the beast" );

print 0+$thing,"\n";
print $thing,"\n";
```

Mostly you won't need to though - this is something that can do really odd things if you meddle too much. But often 'results' are dualvars, such as `$@` and `$!`.

```
open ( my $fh, '<', "not_here"); #generates $!
print "\$! is dual\n" if isdual ( $! );
print 0+$!,"\n";
print $!,"\n
```

This prints:

```
$! is dual
2
No such file or directory
```

In the context of your question - it's because either empty string or zero are 'false' and perl doesn't know what kind of 'false' you'll be needing. So it gives you both.

And because you're doing a `print` perl decides that you're using strings now, and uses the string part of the dual var - the empty string.

You could instead do:

```
print "why... ",0+(1>2), "\n";
```

Adding zero forces a switch to 'numeric' and gives you:

```
why... 0
```

But the long and short of it really is - don't do what you're doing, it's bad style. If you need a particular value if something is false - then spell out what that value is. There's nothing wrong with:

```
return 0 if 1>2;
```

Or:

```
print "Why: ", 1>2 ? "1" : "0", "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have thrown away my book.  By the way， I have the above question becuase of this expression:  $index = (($index - $kIntervals) >> ($index > $kIntervals)) + $kIntervals;         When $index< $kIntervals, i get a strange result  (To me). Maybe the final reason is the shift operator .I still have so much to learn......

Answer (score 2):

I applaud [**Sobrique's** explanation of *dualvars*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44197094/622310) but I don't think it's necessary to involve such esoteric parts of Perl to resolve your problem

Perl's dualvars are much more common than you may imagine, and are used primarily to avoid repeating a conversion between a string and an integer

```
my $v1 = "10";
my $v2 = $v1 + 20;
```

In this example, the variable `$v1` is set to the string `"10"`. That string must be converted to an integer to perform the next operation, which is to add the number `20` and store the result in `$v2`. To avoid repeating the conversion if the numeric version of `$v1` happens to be needed again, it becomes a *dualvar* which holds both the string and the numeric values and evaluates to `"10"` or `10` according to how it is used

All of these are *false* in Perl

- The numeric value zero
- The *string* `"0"`

  (Note than any other strings that evaluate to a numerical zero, such as `"0.0"` or `"0E99"`, are *true*)
- The empty string `""`
- `undef`
- An empty list `( )`

*Anything else is true*, so subroutines and expressions may return pretty much anything for a boolean value as long as it follows these rules. In practice, Perl built-in operators usually return a fixed value for *false* which happens to be a *dualvar* equal to zero as a number and the empty string as a string

> I have the above question because of this expression:
>
> ```
> $index = (($index - $kIntervals) >> ($index > $kIntervals)) + $kIntervals
> ```
>
> When `$index` < `$kIntervals`, I get a strange result (To me). Maybe the final reason is the shift operator

Here, the value `$index > $kIntervals` is used as a number, so its value will be zero or one as you expected. I don't know what result you want from this expression, but `<<` will perform a *logical shift* and treat the first operand as a simple bit pattern. If you want to do an *arithmetic shift*, which is basically a multiplication by a power of two, then you need to temporarily enable `use integer`, like this

```
$index = do {
    use integer;
    ( ( $index - $kIntervals ) >> ( $index > $kIntervals ) ) + $kIntervals;
};
```

but as I don't know what you're doing, that is just as likely to be wrong